# Make Pydantic chuck error for wrong argument names

Tags: pydantic

Suppose I have the following class:

```py
class ModelConfig(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str = "bert"
```

If I were to instantiate it with `model_config = ModelConfig(name2="hello")`, this simply ignores that there is no `name2` and just keeps `name="bert"`. Is there a way to raise an error saying unknown argument in pydantic?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [`forbid` Model Config](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/)

For example:

> class ModelConfig(pydantic.BaseModel, extra=pydantic.Extra.forbid):
> name: str = "bert"

Passing `model_config = ModelConfig(name2="hello")` will throw an error